# jQuery html() not working - firefox unterminated string literal

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, char

I'm trying to add to a `<p>` element the following string:

(with no charset defined)

```
Ð¦ÐµÐ½Ð°: 4,80 BGN ÐŸÐ¾Ð´Ð´Ñ€ÑŠÐ¶ÐºÐ°:
```

(directly from .XML file)

```
&#1062;&#1077;&#1085;&#1072;: 4,80 BGN
```

but it doesn't work, firebug keeps saying:

```
$('#sms_hint p').html('aЦена: 4,80 BGN unterminated string literal
```

and this is how I'm trying to add the html to element:

```
<?php $promo = "&#1062;&#1077;&#1085;&#1072;: 4,80 BGN";?>    
<script>$('#sms_hint p').html('<?php echo $promo;?>a')</script>
```

This is an ajax request, an external .php file which contains all code from above, and if an input is changed this should update the index.php file.

Am I need to convert or encrypt to pass data?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix your php with your javascript that closely.

Try it like this:

```
<script>
var promo = "&#1062;&#1077;&#1085;&#1072;: 4,80 BGN";
$('#sms_hint p').html(promo);
</script>
```